# How can I solve the problem with dash scripts? It keeps returning errors like not writable

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I’m trying to run a simple tutorial script from here: https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started in Jupyter Notebook. At first, I’ve got an error “not writable” and changed the parameters like this:

```
def echo(message=None, file=sys.stdout, nl=True, err=False, color=None):
def secho(text, file=sys.stdout, nl=True, err=False, color=None, **styles):
```

**And now it returns:**

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 1
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2969: UserWarning:
To exit: use ‘exit’, ‘quit’, or Ctrl-D.
```

There are also a localhost page and a debug pin, the localhost page is blank.

I’ve also installed flask=0.12.2 but nothing has changed.

Maybe somebody also ran in the same issue? I would really appreciate some advice.

Comment: as for me `Dash` simple may not work with Jupyter Notebook. Both create web server to run. Better save code in normal file - ie. `script.py` - and run it `python script.py`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Dash from Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478173/launch-dash-from-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: @furas is right, however there are possible work arounds. I presented the best one in my last answer today. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478173/launch-dash-from-jupyter-notebook